# How do i choose different types of the same string

Tags: c#

Title might not be correct but i'm having this problem.

**IDocumentClient[from metadata]:**

```
Task<ResourceResponse<Document>> ReplaceDocumentAsync(Document document, RequestOptions options = null);

Task<ResourceResponse<Document>> ReplaceDocumentAsync(Uri documentCollectionUri, object document, RequestOptions options = null);

Task<ResourceResponse<Document>> ReplaceDocumentAsync(string documentLink, object document, RequestOptions options = null);
```

I'm trying to call ReplaceDocumentAsync but it keeps giving me the wrong one, i want the second one in the list but it automatically gives me the third one, is there a way to choose which string i can use?

I'm calling it like so:

```
public async Task<dynamic> UpdateDocument (Uri reference, object docId, object updatedDoc)
        { 
            return await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(client.CreateDocumentAsync(reference, docId), updatedDoc);
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling this ?

Comment: Then call : ReplaceDocumentAsync(new Uri(...),...

Comment: @user3185569 i'll make an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the bold assumption that your uri is a string; try creating the first parameter as a Uri:

```
var uri = new Uri(myUriString);
doc.ReplaceDocumentAsync(uri, ...);
```